How to identify the spherical function(s) this pattern
The following images show a set of series of spherical lines.
The generation depends upon an octahedral topology (there are six points (p0..p5) which act as 'attractors'(?) - each at where two of the three great circles intersect at 90 degrees.
There is a fixed offset x from those 'attractors'.
There is also an angle of rotation.
The diagram shows x, 2x, 3x, etc.
That is as far as I could go.  I'm not really sure that 'attractor' is the right word - but it seems that maybe the function relates to all six points, an offset of some sort, and a rotation.
It may be that someone here can tell me the actual function - but even knowing how to find the function would be really helpful - though my maths is not good.


What I don't want is a naive subdivision as depicted in the following image. The main aspect here is that the lines above are (getting close to) curves with most triangles approximating equilateral triangles, while below the lines are straight segments, dominated by right-angle triangles.


Your picture looks like what one would get from subdividing the eight triangular faces of a regular octagon and projecting these small triangles onto a sphere, thus forming a geodesic polyhedron. If this is indeed the object you are looking for, what kind of "function" are you seeking? Do you want e.g. an algorithm which, given the level of the subdivision, produces the (spherical) coordinates of all the crossing points (= vertices of those small triangles)?

A simple subdivision looks quite different, Peter. But yes, an algorithm that provides the vertices would be sufficient.
